# Is there such a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Is there a series of the form $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$$ such that it is convergent on $$-1\le x \le 1$$ and divergent on all other real number $x$?

Comment: What happens if $a_n=1/n^2$?

Comment: @SangchuiLee Or something like that, as long as $a_0$ is finite.

Comment: @SangchulLee but isn't $\frac{1}{n^2}$ similar to the harmonic series which is an infinite series?

Comment: @LowZhenHeng Are you aware of the $p$-series?